# switch statement in Android Studio not working

Tags: android, variables, switch-statement

I'm trying to simplify my code, cut down on variables where possible, and I keep getting this error in logcat when my app runs, and the app shuts down:

```
02-14 00:13:10.279  32478-32478/com.example.chris.sunil_gupta W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415998e0)
02-14 00:13:10.289  32478-32478/com.example.chris.sunil_gupta E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chris.sunil_gupta/com.example.chris.sunil_gupta.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 500
```

Could anybody tells me what is wrong with my code? This code works perfect, but I thought I could simplify it a bit:

```
package com.example.chris.sunil_gupta;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    private List <CallData>list = new ArrayList<CallData>();
    private Context context=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ListView listview;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        context=this;

        listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView_CallData);

        getCallDetails();
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void getCallDetails()
    {


        //        cursor1 gets all the items in the calllog and arranges them from newest call down
        Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(
                CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");

//looks like all the cell values in the calllog database are integers
        int number = cursor1.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER );
        int type = cursor1.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
        int date = cursor1.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = cursor1.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

//declare some new variables here; we're going to convert the integers into these
        String callType;
        String phoneNumber;
        String callDate;
        String callDuration;
        Date callDateTime;

//go through all the rows in the db and convert the values to strings or whatever
        while (cursor1.moveToNext())
        {

            phoneNumber = cursor1.getString(number);
            callType = cursor1.getString(type);
            callDate = cursor1.getString(date);

            callDateTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));

            callDuration = cursor1.getString(duration);

//            the string cType will give us text of either outgoing, incoming or missed
            String cType = null;


            int cTypeCode = Integer.parseInt(callType);

            switch(cTypeCode)
            {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    cType = "OUTGOING";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    cType= "INCOMING";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    cType = "MISSED";
                    break;
            }

            CallData calldata=new CallData(cType, phoneNumber, callDateTime, callDuration);
            list.add(calldata);
        }

        cursor1.close();
    }
}
```

This code gives me the errors. Basically I have changed:

```
int type = cursor1.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
```

to

```
String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE));
```

and

replaced the cTypeCode variable with :

```
switch (Integer.parseInt(type))
```

Here's the code that gives me the errors:

```
package com.example.chris.sunil_gupta;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    private List <CallData>list = new ArrayList<CallData>();
    private Context context=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ListView listview;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context=this;

        listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView_CallData);

        getCallDetails();
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void getCallDetails()
    {


        //        cursor1 gets all the items in the calllog and arranges them from newest call down
        Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(
                CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");

//looks like all the cell values in the calllog database are integers
        int number = cursor1.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER );
//        int type = cursor1.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
       String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE));
        int date = cursor1.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = cursor1.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);


//declare some new variables here; we're going to convert the integers into these

        String phoneNumber;
        String callDate;
        String callDuration;
        Date callDateTime;

//go through all the rows in the db and convert the values to strings or whatever
        while (cursor1.moveToNext())
        {

            phoneNumber = cursor1.getString(number);

            callDate = cursor1.getString(date);

            callDateTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));

            callDuration = cursor1.getString(duration);

//            the string cType will give us text of either outgoing, incoming or missed
            String cType = null;

            switch (Integer.parseInt(type))
            {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    cType = "OUTGOING";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    cType= "INCOMING";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    cType = "MISSED";
                    break;
            }

            CallData calldata=new CallData(cType, phoneNumber, callDateTime, callDuration);
            list.add(calldata);
        }

        cursor1.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE));`

This line is outside of your while loop. It will try to read the value of a column while the cursor is at an invalid position (-1) because `moveToNext()` hasn't been called yet. Revert back to looking up the column index and extracting the call type inside the while loop.

Also, you should be using `cursor.getInt()` instead:

```
int callType = cursor.getInt(typeIndex);
switch (callType) {
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks Karakuri, I'm not with Android Studio at the moment. Will look at it later and certainly mark it correct if it works. Why does it work in the first case and not the second? 'int type = cursor1.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );' is outside the while loop too.

Comment: @ChristopheHarris Because in the first case you are only looking up the column index, but in the second case you are also trying to retrieve a value from that column with `getString()`.